# Cassandra - chose comparator for UUID generated with Java JDK

Tags: cassandra, uuid, comparator

I am generating row keys using java:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

What comparator should I use for CF?

```
LexicalUUIDType
UUIDType
TimeUUIDType
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `TimeUUIDType` is for timestamp based (V1) UUIDs. Comparisons are done based on the time field.
- `LexicalUUIDType` is for non time based UUIDs. Comparisons are done lexically, byte by byte.
- `UUIDType` is a unification of the first two. It will detect if two UUIDs are time-based and compare the timestamps; otherwise it will compare lexically.

`UUID.randomUUID()` generates a V4 UUID so it doesn't make sense to use TimeUUIDType. Based on [Cassandra-2233](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2233) it sounds like UUIDType is recommended.